# The call AJAX returned an ORA- 01403 Server Error : No data found for Set Value - ReadOnly Mode

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I m using APEX 4.2

I have an issue with navigation between pages. I have a lot of pages which redirect to a page **X**.

The page X inlcude a Dynamic Action which use an item **P_HDS** (Select List item).

The Item **P_HDS** is readOnly when the user have just the View (Read mode) privilege (he cant modify).

The issue is that when I pass from a page to the page **X** an error is occured : "**The call AJAX returned an ORA- 01403 Server Error : No data found for Set Value .**"

The problem is that the value of **P_HDS** is null so the dynamic action based on this item return this error.

My question is why the **P_HDS** is set de null value just when it s ReadOnly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how did you set that item to read only?

Comment: I set ReadOnly option for some user. the error described is occured when those users are connected on the App